# Making a directory and its contents READ ONLY and UNDELETABLE

Tags: windows-7

I have an archives directory with important files that I don't want myself to accidentally delete or modify. Is it possible make the direcory and its contents READ ONLY and UNDELETABLE?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Set your NTFS permissions on the directory to `Read & execute`, `List folder contents` and `Read`.

Comment: How would one accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some ways:

1) In Explorer, right click the folder, click once to clear the Read-only box, click it again to enable it (as a check mark) "Read Only", hit apply, hit "apply to sub folders and files".

[image]

2) In the command prompt type `attrib c:\FolderName\*.* +R /S /D`.

This will apply the Read-only attribute to the files in the folder and all it's sub-files (/S) including folders (/D).

3) Remove write access for your user via the NTFS permissions for the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can the general proprieties or NTFS permissions to make them readonly.